# Concat the values in a string with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to select a list of items and part numbers for for each item as a string:

```
SELECT top 100 * 
FROM  ii
OUTER APPLY
   (SELECT def, ( ipr.part_number + ',') as prt 
    FROM ipr 
    WHERE ii.item_id = ipr.item_id    
    FOR XML PATH('') ) PN
```

The error is:

> [Error Code: 8155, SQL State: S0002]  No column name was specified for
>   column 1 of 'PN'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I know that `+` operator for concatenation isn't supported by every MySQL version. If the problem comes from the concatenation, I'd suggest to use `CONCAT()` instead.

Comment: What happens when you add an alias for `default_part_number`

Comment: @Kabulan0lak This is SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: @DavidG Oops, I've read MySQL in the title instead of MSSQL. So `+` operator has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: give sample data and expected output

Comment: Part number are like this: C4149A-REMAN
C4149AREMAN
480-0055
4800055
888093
40370603

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your whole `OUTER APPLY` statement generates one XML for both `default_part_number` and concatenated string, which(the whole XML) doesn't have a name.

What you could try to do would be adding alias like this `AS PN(TestThis)`.

However, I don't think that you're expecting result you're going to get. It would better if you'd give us some example data and expected output. It will be easier for us to solve your problem in that case.

Comment: "What you could try to do would be adding alias like this AS PN(TestThis). " it worked. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The combination of XML and STUFF is funny but perfectly fitting to your needs.

First you concat your strings with the ', ' **in front**, then you must return your XML with ", TPYE). You must read the result with ".value()" and use STUFF to replace the first ', '.

You'll find a lot of exampels in the net...